# Adding own plugin to cordova

Tags: java, cordova

I have a problem understanding how to add my own plugin to my cordova(version 4.3.0) project.

I created my project using the CLI:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

I then created a java class named "GeoIntent" which extends cordovaPlugin
in the src folder package

I then tried to add the plugin by adding this text the config.xml

```
<plugin
        name="GeoIntent"
        value="com.example.hello.GeoIntent" />
```

I ran this on android and get this error message

```
D/PluginManager(11760): exec() call to unknown plugin: GeoIntent
```

Comment: You will need to create a plugin package and install the plugin with `cordova plugin add /PATH/TO/PLUGIN` instructions here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment indicated, making a plugin package would be the best option.

That said, you'd need to add something like this (this is for the Device core plugin) to your android project's `config.xml`:

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
```

Comment: if you use the plugin package and put that on the plugin.xml you don't have to manually add this to the config.xml, it is copied on the plugin install